# SQLITE3 VACUUM, "database or disk is full"

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to run the `VACUUM` command on my database, but I seem to run out of space:

```
> sqlite3 mydatabase.db "VACUUM"
Error: database or disk is full
```

The database is about 36 GB and the drive that I'm running it on looks like (via `df -h`):

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       406G  171G  215G  45% /home
```

So I am clearly above the double size limited needed. What can I do to allow the vacuum command to run?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To allow the VACUUM command to run, change the directory for temporary files to one that has enough free space.

SQLite's [documentation](https://sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#tempdir) says the temporary directory is (in order):

1. whatever is set with the [PRAGMA temp_store_directory](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_temp_store_directory) command; or
2. whatever is set with the `SQLITE_TMPDIR` environment variable; or
3. whatever is set with the `TMPDIR` environment variable; or
4. `/var/tmp`; or
5. `/usr/tmp`; or
6. `/tmp`; or
7. `.`, the current working directory

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow. The PRAGMA link mentions that this is a depriecated command but doesn't give the alternative. Is the enviorment variable the recommended way?

Comment: Yes, but everything except `PRAGMA temp_store_directory` is OS-dependent.

Comment: Note, that `SQLITE_TMPDIR` was only introduced in SQLite v3.8.1...  
See https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_1.html

Answer (score 15):

The **OP** noted that during a VACUUM, SQLite creates a temporary file that is approximately the same size as the original database.  It does this in order to maintain the database ACID properties.  SQLite uses a directory to hold the temporary files it needs while doing the VACUUM.  In order to determine what directory to use, it descends a hierarchy  looking for the first directory that has the proper access permissions.  If it finds a directory that it doesn't have access to, it will ignore that directory and continue to descend the hierarchy looking for one that it does.  I mention this in case anyone has specified an environment variable and SQLite seems to be ignoring it.

In his answer **CL** gives the hierarchy for **Linux** and in his comment mentions that the hierarchy is OS-dependent.  For completeness, here is the hierarchies (in so far as I can determine them from the code).

For **Unix** (and **Linux**) the hierarchy is:

1. Whatever is specified by the *SQLITE_TMPDIR* environment variable,
2. Whatever is specified by the *TMPDIR* environment variable,
3. /var/tmp,
4. /usr/tmp,
5. /tmp, and finally
6. The current working directory.

For **Cygwin** the hierarchy is:

1. Whatever is specified by the *SQLITE_TMPDIR* environment variable,
2. Whatever is specified by the *TMPDIR* environment variable,
3. Whatever is specified by the *TMP* environment variable,
4. Whatever is specified by the *TEMP* environment variable,
5. Whatever is specified by the *USERPROFILE* environment variable,
6. /var/tmp,
7. /usr/tmp,
8. /tmp, and finally
9. The current working directory.

For **Windows** the hierarchy is:

- *GetTempPath()*, which is documented to return:

  1. Whatever is specified by the *TMP* environment variable,
  2. Whatever is specified by the *TEMP* environment variable,
  3. Whatever is specified by the *USERPROFILE* environment variable, and finally
  4. the *Windows* directory.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the drive, where your temporary files are created, has not enough space. See here
[Vacuum-command-is-failing-with-SQL-Error-Database-or-disk-is-full](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/quot-Vacuum-quot-command-is-failing-with-quot-SQL-Error-Database-or-disk-is-full-quot-td48238.html)

Comment: The link you shared is now dead. This is why it's always encouraged to repeat linked information within answers here, rather than just linking. At least The Archive [has copies](https://web.archive.org/web/20180615000000*/http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/quot-Vacuum-quot-command-is-failing-with-quot-SQL-Error-Database-or-disk-is-full-quot-td48238.html) of [that page](https://web.archive.org/web/20180710112039/http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/quot-Vacuum-quot-command-is-failing-with-quot-SQL-Error-Database-or-disk-is-full-quot-td48238.html)