# Python SQLite - How to configure it to use another temporary directory

Tags: python, sqlite

I have Python code that uses SQLite. However, when running on a large database (7 GB) I get the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: database or disk is full
```

I understand it is related to the temporary directory when it creates the tmp files.

How can I configure the Python SQLite to use another directory (one that I will set it up with enough storage for the tmp files).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLITE3 VACUUM, "database or disk is full"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249843/sqlite3-vacuum-database-or-disk-is-full)