# SQLite "Runtime Error: database or disk full (13)" while running vacuum

Tags: sqlite

After running `export SQLITE_TMPDIR=/run/media/ghostdog/data/datadir` I then run `sqlite3 database.db` and subsequently `vacuum;` in the sqlite console. Despite having more than enough room in my new TMPDIR (201gb) while my database is half of that (116.32Gb), after a while of running, sqlite complains `Runtime Error: database or disk full (13)`.

I have confirmed that I am indeed writing to my new TMPDIR by running `while true; do df -kh; sleep .1; clear; done;` in another console, and I am able to watch the `Avail.` and `Use%` go up until the sqlite instance either crashes or throws the aforementioned error. (Yes I am watching the correct directory, I am watching the entry mounted on `/run/media/ghostdog/data/`).

No other processes are running on this disk, and it is not my system disk, so I am sure that nothing else could be filling it (on top of this the `Avail.` field only goes down while `vacuum;` is running).

Comment: And yes, I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249843/sqlite3-vacuum-database-or-disk-is-full) question, but it does not apply to my situation, as I have already changed the TMPDIR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by freeing up enough space for 2 ***additional*** copies of my database, not just 2 copies in total. (So in my case, 232.64GB free)